# What is the benefit of using a stack versus just a doubly linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, stack, quicksort

As an assignment, I have to implement quicksort iteratively rather than recursively. In doing this, I need to use stacks. What is the benefit of using stacks in this scenario versus just a singly or doubly linked list?

Comment: Note that a stack is basically a linked list where you only add, remove or read the head.

Comment: Technically, you could use a queue or a stack for an iterative quicksort, and either (queue or stack) could be implemented as a linked list, with O(1) time complexity for push() or pop().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Push has O(1) and Pop has O(1) time complexity in stack while Inserting may have O(N) (the best case occurs if you add to head, O(1)) and searching has a O(N) in linkedList. Since you need to perform both add and retrive operation, it would be more expensive to utilize LinkedList

Comment: This is not true at all. You can implement a stack as a linked list, always adding to and removing from the head. Both operations are O(1).

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is expressiveness. As was pointed out in comments, you can implement a stack with a linked list. The nice thing about "using a stack" is that you don't have to worry about the details of the implementation. That is, if you just used a linked list, you'd have something like:

```
// push onto the stack
newNode = createStackNode(myData);
newNode.Next = root;
root = newNode;

// pop from stack
poppedNode = root;
root = root.Next;
myData = poppedNode.data;
```

If you use an existing `Stack` data structure, then you don't have to worry about the details of pushing and popping. All you have to write is:

```
theStack.push(myData);
```

or

```
myData = theStack.pop();
```

Point being that you know the `Stack` data structure works. And it's really difficult to goof up a call to `push` or `pop`. It's *very easy* to screw up code that adds things to and removes things from the head of a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

The stack is an interface that define a set of operations that should be defined and it can be implemented in many ways, with a linked list, a double linked list, an array, ect.(also with queues if you want, even if I don't suggest so). The definition of this set of operations limit the scope of the data structure, allowing to get better performances for the specific use case.

In general to remove an element from a linked list or an array it takes `O(n)` because the element you want to remove could be in any position, so you have to find it first. In a stack, implementing `pop` with the same data structures you can achieve `O(1)` because you already know where is the element to remove (it's the head in case o linked list and the last element in case of array).